# Combining two list of lists into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

There are two lists of lists, I need to make one list out of them.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
I_need = [[1,1,2,2,3,3],[4,4,5,5,6,6]]
```

or one more question, how to duplicate the list to have the same result.
I will be glad for any help!

Comment: why `numpy`? are these lists or arrays?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right. If you want a hand getting started check out `zip(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you marked your question with *Numpy* tag, I assume that you
want to use just *Numpy*.

To easier tell apart elements of both source arrays, I defined them as:

```
a = [[ 1, 2, 3],[ 4, 5, 6]]
b = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60]]
```

To get your expected result, run:

```
result = np.dstack([a, b]).reshape(2, -1)
```

The result is:

```
array([[ 1, 10,  2, 20,  3, 30],
       [ 4, 40,  5, 50,  6, 60]])
```

If you want a plain pythonic **list** (instead of a Numpy array),
append *.tolist()* to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python lists:

```
I_need = [[e for x in zip(*l) for e in x] for l in zip(a,b)]
```

output: `[[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]]`

If you have numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
I_need = np.c_[a.ravel(), b.ravel()].reshape(2,-1)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]])
```

Comment: I think this is a slightly simpler version of your comprehension `[sorted(x+y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]`

Comment: @JonSG I guess sorting is cheating ;) This doesn't generalize to any input

Comment: True enough, I'm just going by one admittedly naive interpretation of the output :-)